# PayPal - can payer be different from the subscriber?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am using PayPal's Enhanced Recurring Payments (ERP) and the REST APIs to allow users to buy a subscription to our online service.

We often have one payer purchasing subscriptions for others. When that payer gets his recurring payment email, only the payer's name appears and not the user's name.

Is there any way to include both the payer's name and the user's name on the receipt, IPNs and other communications from PayPal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to build that into your app.  For example, you could have them enter the payer and subscriber details in a form prior to sending them over to PayPal.  Save those details in your database and then pass the record ID over to PayPal along with the payment details.  You could use the invoice parameter for the custom parameter for this, for example.

That value would then come back in IPN so you could easily query your database to pull all the details back out and process things accordingly.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. In fact, I do exactly what you say (leveraging the custom parameter). However, when PayPal makes the recurring payment, it sends an email to the payer -- that email doesn't reveal the user's name, leaving the payer confused about which 1 of many subscriptions was paid.

The alternative might be for me to suppress the email from PayPal and substitute an email of my own. I'm trying to avoid that extra work. :)

Comment: Yeah, nothing you're going to be able to do about the email that PayPal sends.  You're going to have to make your own email and send it through IPN.  Shouldn't be much more work, though, and then you can brand it and make it a lot nicer than PayPal's email beyond just ensuring it has all the detail you need.

Comment: Good point about the branding/etc. of my own email. And it won't be much more work (though any work is more work under our current deadline!!)

Thanks again.